# zend framework 2 : Set session authentification timeout

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the problem that the authentification session doesn't expire , this is my code of authentification :

```
$adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.authenticationadapter.orm_default');
$adapter->setOptions(array(
    'objectManager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
    'identityClass' => 'Application\Entity\User',
    'identityProperty' => 'email',
    'credentialProperty' => 'password'));

$adapter->setIdentityValue($mail);
$adapter->setCredentialValue($password);
$authService = new AuthenticationService();
$result = $authService->authenticate($adapter);

if ($result->isValid()) 
{
    $identity = $result->getIdentity();
    $authService->getStorage()->write($identity);
    echo "valide"; 
}
else
    echo "invalide";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you written all of the code on your own? If not, what external modules are you using? Have you got any session configuration in your config (`/config/autoload/*` but also in any module configuration? How about extra config in `Module.php`?

Comment: @ThomasDutrion no i haven nothing other about session config or about auth config.

Comment: Then it might come from your underlying PHP configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved my problem :

```
if ($result->isValid()) 
{
     $session = new Container('Zend_Auth');
     $session->setExpirationSeconds(1800);
    $identity = $result->getIdentity();
    $authService->getStorage()->write($identity);
    echo "valide"; 
}
else
    echo "invalide";
```

I get the Object session `Zend_Auth` , then i edited the value of expiration time.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You should see https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

for identity provider. 
and then in config: configure the role_providers.